# 2 Pipe Problem, why does my parent process keep waiting?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, wait

I am trying to make a program containing 2 pipes, and in my program, the child will run first, the parent will run at the end.
The result shows that Child 2, then Child1, and keep pending.
It seems my parent is still waiting for some child process to be finished, but I only got 2 child process in this program~ Please help me :) Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pipefd[2];
    int pipefd2[2];
    int rv= pipe(pipefd);
    assert(rv > -1);
    int cid = fork();
    assert(cid > -1);
    int status;
    if( cid > 0 ){
        //waitpid(cid,NULL,0);
        printf("P %d %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Parent \n");
        close(0);
        dup(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);

        char *const wc_argv[] = {"wc", "-l", NULL};
        execvp("wc", wc_argv);
        //Parent - Redirect stdout to the write end of the pipe, and execute "ls -l"

    }else{
        int rv1= pipe(pipefd2);
        assert(rv1 > -1);
        int cid1 = fork();
        assert(cid1 > -1);

        if(cid1>0){
            printf("C1 %d %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Child1\n");
            //Child 1 (parent of child 2)
            close(0);
            dup(pipefd[0]);
            close(1);
            dup(pipefd2[1]);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[1]);
            close(pipefd2[0]);
            close(pipefd2[1]);
            char *const grep_argv[] = {"grep", "D", NULL};
            execvp("grep", grep_argv);
        }else{
            printf("C2 %d %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            printf("Child2\n");
            //Child 2 (child of child 1)
            close(1);
            dup(pipefd2[1]);
            close(pipefd2[0]);
            close(pipefd2[1]);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[1]);
            char *const ls_argv[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
            execvp("ls", ls_argv);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy the output of your program when running.  Are you seeing the output of the "ls" and "grep" commands?

Comment: I don't see the error. Maybe you should try with one pipe first.

Comment: Side issue: do not use assertions to check function return values, or to perform any other non-optional test or computation.  Depending on compilation context, assertions may be completely ignored during compilation.

Comment: Another side issue: use `dup2()` instead of `close()` + `dup()`.  The former is clearer and safer.  Use `dup()` only when the value of the duplicate file descriptor doesn't matter.

Comment: How are the pipes supposed to be connected between the processes? `pipefd[0]` and `pipefd2[1]` have not been `dup`d at all.

Comment: I guess you intended to pipe the standard output of child2 ("ls -l") to the standard input of child1 ("grep D") and the standard output of child1 to the standard input of the parent ("wc -l"), but the pipes are not connected like that at all.

Comment: Depending on the pipe length and amount of output from "ls -l", it is possible for child2 to block when writing to the pipe, because nothing is reading the other end of the pipe.

Comment: Child1 is blocked reading its standard input from the first pipe because nothing is writing to the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code.  I pointed out some minor matters in comments, but the ones mainly likely to be responsible for the misbehavior you describe are:

- Child 1 and the parent both redirect `pipefd[0]` to their standard inputs.  Probably you want child 1 to redirect `pipefd2[0]` to its standard input instead, but you definitely don't want the two to have the same standard input.
- Child 1 redirects its standard output to `pipefd2[1]`, the other end of which pipe will be its standard input once you correct the previous issue.  You appear to instead want to redirect to `pipefd[1]`, which presently is not served at all.
- Child 1 waits for child 2 before it proceeds.  This is non-idiomatic and risky, for you will get a deadlock if child 2 fills the buffer of the second pipe, and therefore blocks before terminating.  Pipes are data conduits. Although they do have internal buffers, this should be regarded as an implementation detail.  It is incorrect to rely on pipes for buffering.  The correct model is that data is consumed from the pipe's read end concurrently with data being written to the pipe's write end.
- The parent waits for child 1 before it proceeds.  As with child 1's wait, this is risky and non-idiomatic.

Additionally, as @IanAbott remarked in comments, with the way you are arranging the pipes, child 1 waiting for child 2 will reliably produce deadlock.  The latter execs a program that will read its standard input to the end, but it will not see EOF on its input until the other ends of the pipe is closed, and that is never closed because child 1 waits on child 2 to finish before it proceeds.  I see no necessity for the waits -- neither child 1's nor the parent's -- they could and should just be removed.

Comment: Even if child 1 succeeds in waiting for child 2, it then dups `pipefd[0]` to standard input before execing "grep", but "grep" will block reading standard input because nothing is writing the other end of the pipe and not everyone has closed it yet. In particular, the parent has not closed `pipefd[1]` yet because it is still waiting for child 1 to exit first.

Comment: Yes, @IanAbbott, my first point is that child 1 is redirecting the wrong pipe to its standard input.  But you are right that I failed to mention that the parent process also waits for child 1, producing substantially the same issues as are involved with child 1 waiting for child 2.  I will add that.

Comment: Indeed, there seems no reason for any of the processes to call `wait` at all in this example, unless OP is just experimenting with its effect.

Comment: And you have a larger point there, too, @IanAbbott, which I think I have now addressed.

Comment: About the additional point you addressed, it is only child 1 and the parent that read standard input from a pipe. Child 2 and child 1 both write standard output to a pipe. (Not the correct pipes though.)

Answer (score 0):

OMG!! Thanks ALL
This is my first time posting a question in stack overflow.
I cant believe you guys are so helpful, thank you so much
and i have solved my problem right now.
I can believe I just made a really simple mistake, which is in Child1

```
        close(0);
        dup(pipefd2[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(pipefd[1]);
```

Original, my program will run parent first, then i want to modify it, then i just thought exchanging the child 2 and parent, everything will be fine, but i forgot to modify the content of child1.
Anyways, you guys are so helpful, and hope you guys stay safe and keep going on our it adventure :)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I can see there are a lot of recommendations for my code, I will try to digest it :). Thanks all again!!